# Stop running the script error in IE8 while using JCarousel

Tags: jcarousel

I am using JCarousel in my application to display images from the DB to my web page.In FireFox JCarousel is working fine **but when the web page is loaded in IE8 browser it throws this error**

```
Stop running the script? The script on this page is causing IE to run slowly.
If it continues to run your computer might become unresponsive.
```

can any one pls help me solve this problem by providing suggestions,ideas,sample coding.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "issue" is IE, but it is actually trying to be helpful and allow the user to stop long running scripts with the assumption that this is a malicious or badly coded script.

Here are the details and it can be turned off, but must be done by the user:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175500

Here are some more details also:

[a script on this page is causing ie to run slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212550/a-script-on-this-page-is-causing-ie-to-run-slowly)

I'm using a few Telerik controls and have no way to change their code. I'm still looking for a better way to deal with this too.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue, but just in case. This issue went away as soon as I upgraded my jQuery version from 1.4.4 to 1.7.0+.