# "Stop running this script" error in IE7 and IE8 while trying to navigate to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, openlayers

I have created a Drupal website that uses Openlayers to display maps. In one of these maps there are some "Filters" which the user can use to dynamically change the data shown in the map. The data are related to countries are shown as bubbles over the countries. The bubbles are drawn using Openlayers' API. A good amount of calculations go behind the scene while filters are selected. I have used setTimeout to avoid long running loops. The filters work fine. However, after a number of filters are clicked (e.g. if 12 filters are clicked), if the user tries to move to another page by clicking a link, in IE7 and IE8 the following error shows -

"Stop running this script?

A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly.
If it continues to run, your computer might become unresponsive."

This error does not show in any other browser and does not show in IE7, 8 until a link is clicked. Any pointer in this regard will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE** : The problem was in OpenLayers' event cache. OpenLayers's clears the event cache in the window unload event and this was getting stuck in IE7 and IE8 (I am not sure why). So far I have been able to solve the issue when user clicks another link, by calling OpenLayers.Event.unloadCache() on click of normal links.

Comment: If you put a link to the page we can take a look to the code.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery can be very resource expensive. The articles linked bellow gives you 10 good advices to perform better your jQuery applications. The most useful for me (I had the same problem a month ago) was to replace $.each() with traditional for lops and to replace extensive DOM construction  with jquery templates. Also the use of ID instead of classes and to give a context for the selectors, selector caching, and so on.

This list is ordered using my own criteria of "usefulness" in the advices.

1. [10 ways to instantly increase your jquery performance](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance/)
2. [improve your jquery 25 excellent tips](http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx)
3. [10 advanced jquery performance tuning tips from paul irish](http://jonraasch.com/blog/10-advanced-jquery-performance-tuning-tips-from-paul-irish)
4. [8 jquery performance tips](http://addyosmani.com/blog/8-jquery-performance-tips/)

Comment: Thanks. I do have a number of $.each(). Will try to replace them and let you know what I get.

Answer (score 0):

You need to optimize your client script. Please refer to answers [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212550/a-script-on-this-page-is-causing-ie-to-run-slowly)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I had already checked that discussion. Also, I had checked the tool recommended by Remy Sharp; but could not get much out of it. The main problem for me is that I can't find the code that is creating the problem as the message does not show until a link is clicked.